# main function with respect to C

Tags: c

```
5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined
with a return type of int and with no parameters.
```

I have defined like this,

`int main(int a, int b, int c){.......}`

It works. I didn't understood the first line `"The implementation declares no prototype for this function"`

Need help, Thanks

Comment: Is your question about what the first line means, or why your declaration "works"?

Comment: @Barmar: Why my definition of main works.

Answer (score 4):

All it means is that `main` is not declared in advance.  There's no line like

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]);
```

and that means that when you define the function, you can pretend it takes any arguments and returns any type you like without getting a compiler error.

Of course, `main` is called by the operating system, so it will expect your definition to match whatever convention it uses for passing parameters.  In practice, except on embedded systems, your definiton for main has to match the above.

Answer (score 2):

When you are making a prototype then it means that you want to call it elsewhere which is not the case for `main` function.

From the [docs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):-

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
>   defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> int main(int argc, char `*argv[]`) { /* ... */ }
>
> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Your 2nd signature of main is wrongly quoted - cf. `char *argv[]`.

Comment: @maxschlepzig:- It was right but when I quoted it then * was missed!!! Updated that :)

Answer (score 1):

`declaration or prototype` is not require for `main` function

functions other than `main` requires **declaration and 
definition**

```
int sum(int,int); //declaration
int sum(int a,int b) //definition
{
//body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You left out the rest of the quote from that section of the standard, I am going to quote the C99 draft standard which says:

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

The `shall be defined` is the quote is the important part, it says it must follow one of these two signatures or if available some implementation specific signature which would be defined by the compiler implementor.

If I attempt to build this in the latest version of `clang` I see the following errors:

```
error: second parameter of 'main' (argument array) must be of type 'char **'
  int main(int a, int b, int c){}
error: third parameter of 'main' (environment) must be of type 'char **'
```

Comment: What if I define the main as int main(int a, int b, int c)?

Comment: @Patil It is not allowed by the standard you have two choices which are detailed in section `5.1.2.2.1` if your compiler allows it it is not standards compliant or less likely it has some implementation defined signature but then it has to document that.